# Start from login screen from reload

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I have an app with a login screen and every time someone exits the app I want the login screen to be displayed when they come back.  What setting would this be under? I also need to make sure it doesn't mimic first load because I have code that only needs to be run the first time the app is ever open.

Thanks for the help

My code that I have from Avi's help,

```
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(myLoginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Save some variable in `NSUserDefaults`, at the start check it, if have, then show login screen

Answer (score 2):

In order to perform a task when the user come back to your app, implement `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` in the app delegate, or listen to `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification.

If you want to know if it's the user first time in the app, set a flag in NSUserDefaults.

If the login screen is a view controller, you can present it from the app delegate, linking it to the root view controller.

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: how would I say go back to login screen because I normally just perform a segue that links back to the login. Is there a way to do that in the app delegate?

Comment: I get an error, expect member name or constructor call after type name for my loginController

Comment: loginController was just an example. You need to put it your loginController instance of course.